# Error with barryvadh laravel dom-pdf when try to create pdf from blade.php file

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using barryvdh's library DOMPdf to generate pdf documents from html.code of the in my reports.blade.php as shown belows.i want to create a pdf using reports.blade.php.when i click download pdf link it gives error saying undifined "user " variable.

```
<a href="{{url('/pdfs')}}">Download pdf</a>

@foreach ($users as $user) 

<font size="6"> 
 <ol> {{$user->name}}
    {{$user->lname}}</font><br>

@endforeach
```

but i run this laravel  project it gives a error calling undifened variable.

codes of the reportGenerator controller as shown below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use PDF;

class pdfGenerator extends Controller
{
    public function reportPdf(){
   $pdf  = PDF::loadview('reports');
   return $pdf->download('report.pdf');
   }


  public function report()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();

        return view('reports', ['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

why there is a error occur calling undefined variable. but without following code part i can download empty pdf.

```
@foreach ($users as $user) 

<font size="6"> 
 <ol> {{$user->name}}
    {{$user->lname}}</font><br>

@endforeach
```

routes which i used as below

```
Route::get('/pdfs','pdfGenerator@reportPdf');

Route::get('/reports','pdfGenerator@report');
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any other `$user` in another place of this file?

Comment: i am sure.there is no error occur without this code part@foreach ($users as $user) 

<font size="6"> 
 <ol> {{$user->name}}
    {{$user->lname}}</font><br>

@endforeach                            .I can download blank pdf without that.error occur when iinclude above code part

Comment: show us your error stack trace

Comment: sorry i did not understand what is error stack trace.but that error occur when i used above codes.before that all the parts of my project work correctly

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined variable: users (View: E:\nimnayawebsite\resources\views\reports.blade.php) this is the error

Comment: You need to pass the users into loadView in your `reportPdf` function

Comment: i tried it.but it is not solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the `$users` variable to `view` as a second parameter.

```
public function reportPdf()
{
   $users = DB::table('users')->get();
   $pdf  = PDF::loadview('reports', ['users' => $users]); 


   return $pdf->download('report.pdf');
}
```

Comment: sorry still it not working.is it error with barryvadh laravel dom-pdf.

Comment: thank you very much.now it is working.Can you briefly explain why this occur.please recommand for areas which i should further study

Comment: you need to pass a array of parameter to view as a second parameter on loadView() function. If you want to learn more about this, then try to see the issues with this packages on github.

Comment: thank you too, and don't forget to accept it as it may help others

Comment: sorry i do not have sufficent reputations to accept this answer.when i reach that i accept this.thank you very much

Comment: @MihiranChathuranga you don't need reputation to accept, just click on tick sign on left of your question under downvote sign

Comment: we all know things day by day :)